# Java Read Data From Serial Port

Tags: java, rxtx

I wrote a Java Program to read serial port data using rxtx. It worked successfully in a 32 bit windows system of mine.However when i used the same code on 64 bit with rxtxcomm.jar and rxtxserial.dll changed it is not working.I downloaded the rxtx files from their site for 64 bit and still it is not working,it seems the dll is meant for 32 bit only . Is there a dll for 64 bit available? I need help in this matter as code is working fine on 32 bit system. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

download the rxtx for 64 bit from the link : http://mfizz.com/oss/rxtx-for-java

Also the rxtxSerial.dll and rxtxParallel.dll for 64 bit is already present.

Please follow the installation instruction inside it.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i tried that link and still it does not work.I got the solution by trying with jssc which works in both 32 and 64

Answer (score 0):

RXTX binary builds provided as a courtesy of Fizzed, Inc. (http://fizzed.com/).
Please see http://fizzed.com/oss/rxtx-for-java for more information.